Rational point on a pythagorean rectangle

Consider the rectangle shown in the above diagram with vertices $(0,0)$, $(a,0)$, $(0,b)$ and $(a,b)$. The sides and diagonals of this rectangle are integers i.e., $a, b, c$ are integers such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.
$P$ is called a rational point if it is at rational distances from all the four vertices of the rectangle.
Question 1: Are there any rational points on the sides of the rectangle (other than the four vertices)? If the answer is yes, are there infinitely many such points?
Question 2: Are there any rational points inside the rectangle (other than the center point)? If the answer is yes, are there infinitely many such points?
Question 3: Are there any rational points outside the rectangle? If the answer is yes, are there infinitely many such points?
I would like to know if the answer to these questions are known to be true/false (or) are they open problems?
I have formulated these questions after reading about the 4-distance problem, the famous long-standing open problem.
4-distance problem asks if there exists a point $P(x, y)$ on the 2-dimensional Euclidean plane such that the distance $PA, PB, PC, PD$ are all rational numbers, where $ABCD$ is a unit square $A(0, 0), B(1, 0), C(0, 1), D(1, 1)$.

Clearly the midpoint meets your requirements since distances are 1/2 c, which is rational.

I am looking for non-trivial solutions. I have added more clarifications and different versions of my question.

Now we have more questions. Please ask one question per post. Please do not add any further questions to a given question, which double or even completely change the amount of work. Beyond this: Please provide context for the question. As it stays now we have an isolated question, which has an implicit connection to elliptic curves. Stating it naively with a raw picture of a rectangle, in a simple geometric context is very misleading. The real question is in fact a diophantine question. Please show what you tried, your attempt to get closer to a solution. Please give references.

This is an answer to the initial question. It wanted only rational points on the sides of the given rectangle.
We may want to switch $a,b$ to search for points on the side of length $b$ (and first on the line supporting it). Such a point cuts the segment of length $b$ in two pieces of lengths $s,t$, and we have to solve in rational numbers:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
s + t &= b\ ,\\
s^2 + a^2 &= S^2\ ,\\ 
t^2 + a^2 &= T^2\ .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
(The point is on the side of the rectangle, iff $s,t\ge 0$.)
Observe that for $(s,t,S,T)$ we have the particular solutions
$(0,b,a,c)$ and $(b,0,c,a)$.
We eliminate $t$ first by using $t=b-s$, so the second equation is successively

$(b-s)^2 + a^2 = T^2$, then
$(s^2 -2bs + b^2) + a^2 = T^2$, then
$S^2 - T^2  + b^2 = 2bs$, then
$(S^2 - T^2  + b^2)^2 = 4b^2s^2$, then
$(S^2 - T^2  + b^2)^2 = 4b^2(S^2-a^2)$, then
$S^4 - 2S^2T^2 + T^4  - 2b^2S^2 - 2b^2T^2 + 4a^2b^2 + b^4 = 0$.

(It turns out that the above algebraic equation defines the affine part of a genus one curve. We want an explicit Weierstrass parametrization for it.)
Let us denote by $\Sigma$ the value $\Sigma=S^2$. We obtain a $2:1$ covering from the curve $(C)$ defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
(C)\qquad 
0&=
S^4 - 2S^2T^2 + T^4  - 2b^2S^2 - 2b^2T^2 + 4a^2b^2 + b^4 \ ,\qquad\text{ i.e.}
\\
0&=
S^4 - 2S^2(T^2 + b^2) + (T^2-b^2)^2 + 4a^2b^2\ ,\qquad\text{ i.e.}
\end{aligned}
$$
to the curve $(C_0)$ defined by
$$
(C_0)\qquad
0 = \Sigma^2 - 2\Sigma (T^2+b^2) + (T^2 - b^2)^2 + 4a^2b^2 \ .
$$
The curve $(C_0)$ admits a rational parametrization. We can solve for $\Sigma$,
$$
\Sigma_\pm = (T^2+b^2)\pm 2ab\sqrt{\left(\frac Ta\right)^2-1}\ ,
$$
Under the radical we arrange for a perfect square using $T/a=(u^2+1)/(2u)$.
The corresponding substitution is thus
$$
T=\frac a{2u}(u^2+1)\ .
$$
Then the whole radical is $(u^2-1)/(2u)$, and the sign of $u$ can be used to also cover the role of $\pm$ in the formula. We obtain an equation in $(S,u)$ of the shape:
$$
S^2 = 
\frac {a^2}{4u^2}(u^2+1)^2
+
\frac{ab}u(u^2-1)
+ b^2
\ .
$$
Let $v$ be $v=2Su$. Then we multiply above by $4u^2$ on both sides and rewrite:
$$
(C')\qquad
v^2=a^2(u^2+1)^2 + 4ab\;u(u^2-1) + 4b^2 u^2
\ .
$$
This is the (affine) equation of a hyperelliptic curve of genus one $(C')$, it may be brought in the Weierstrass form, and so we obtain (birationally) an elliptic $(E)$.
$$
(E)\qquad
y^2 -4bxy + 8a^2by = x^3 + 2a^2 x^2 -4a^4x - 8a^6 
\ .
$$
(We may further divide by $a^6$, and substitute $X=x/a^2$, and so on...)
The points $(\pm 2a^2,0)$, and $(-2a^2,-16a^2b)$ are easy points on $(E)$.
They are in fact $2$-torsion points.
There are finitely many rational points in the same time on $(C')$ and $(E)$,
also infinitely many in the same time.
Going back to the rectangle, we obtain points on the specific chosen line,
supported by the chosen side.
They may or may not be on the side (seen as a segment).
But ok, this should be enough for a general discussion.
Some special analysis of some special cases is following now.

(1) The triangle with the sides $a,b,c$ equal to $3,4,5$:
The curve $(C')$ has the equation:
$$
v^2 = 9 u^{4} + 48 u^{3} + 82 u^{2} - 48 u + 9\ .
$$
The points $(u,v)=(\pm3,0)$ are special points on the curve.
We use the transformation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &=\frac 6{u^2}(v-5)\ ,\qquad&
u &=\frac 6y(x + 18)
\\
y &= \frac {12}{u^3}(3v + -24u + 41u^2 - 276)\ ,\qquad&
v &= \frac 16u(ux+48)-3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This leads to the elliptic curve with equation:
$$
(E)\qquad
y^2 - 16xy + 288y = x^3 + 18x^2  - 324x - 5832\ .
$$
It has the torsion points $(\pm 18,0)$, $(-18,-576)$, and $\infty$.
It has rank one, and one generator (of the free part of $E(\Bbb Q)$) is $(-90,-432)$.
This leads to an infinity of points on the line supported by the side of length $b=4$, some of them have the $x$-component between $0$ and $4$. Here are some such rational points:
$$
\tiny
\begin{aligned}
4 &= \underbrace{\frac{6853121}{13563960}}_{\approx0.505244854747434} + \underbrace{\frac{47402719}{13563960}}_{\approx3.49475514525257}\\[2mm]
4 &= \underbrace{\frac{147594982174023047259596}{150056170948485868193999}}_{\approx0.983598216861686} + \underbrace{\frac{452629701619920425516400}{150056170948485868193999}}_{\approx3.01640178313831}\\[2mm]
4 &= \underbrace{\frac{653877272156457093117052646187942309012615608549}{451982123412961996391745640284070929813369679900}}_{\approx1.44668834957225} + \underbrace{\frac{1154051221495390892449929914948341410240863111051}{451982123412961996391745640284070929813369679900}}_{\approx2.55331165042775}\\[2mm]
4 &= \underbrace{\frac{2117450258007418075102570736926299290816882633118593680021123030121471908900842600}{1113004830793770002282460041244864260800254406893628827113269405691533709285221001}}_{\approx1.90246277412588}
\\
&\qquad+ \underbrace{\frac{2334569065167661934027269428053157752384134994455921628431954592644662928240041404}{1113004830793770002282460041244864260800254406893628827113269405691533709285221001}}_{\approx2.09753722587412}\\[2mm]
4 &= \underbrace{\frac{1227581682017069615857973410010022374662923569322665377841381446512306861184375842254002433623708697782283810324302532748479}{747167284140752211701712802143608855972810001488528275215531513809196586139530583182301932123529012295600583752328880175840}}_{\approx1.64298104062305}
\\
&\qquad+ \underbrace{\frac{1761087454545939230948877798564413049228316436631447723020744608724479483373746490475205294870407351400118524685012987954881}{747167284140752211701712802143608855972810001488528275215531513809196586139530583182301932123529012295600583752328880175840}}_{\approx2.35701895937695}\\[2mm]
4 &= \underbrace{\frac{485560295638018248708148605259946825050226226686938358827503839623615977374255797890542719519519018287960310822949621042819407064506577564314189374264744998576493155210823000}{410149458865207669613819153291377784118553526362235351785894978723039748541709718486662964003979571108205905049751053896892462688376443201654648675588018560045137866165154999}}_{\approx1.18386184631684}
\\
&\qquad+ \underbrace{\frac{1155037539822812429747128007905564311423987878762003048316076075268543016792583076056109136496399266144863309376054594544750443688999195242304405328087329241604058309449796996}{410149458865207669613819153291377784118553526362235351785894978723039748541709718486662964003979571108205905049751053896892462688376443201654648675588018560045137866165154999}}_{\approx2.81613815368316}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Each line is of the shape $b=s+t$, where $b=4$. And the numbers $s,t$ "mot-a-mot" extracted from each such line
are so that both $s^2+a^2$ and $t^2+a^2$ are squares of rational numbers, here $a=4$.
As an example, placing the solution in the geometric context:

Note that together with $(s,t)$ the point $(t,s)$ is also a solution.
A "smaller" solution has for instance $s=-11/20$ and $t=4-s=91/20$, but must be rejected
by the requirement that the corresponding point is on one side (and not on its prolongation, on its supporting line).
(In this case $(-11/20)^2+3^2=(61/20)^2$ and $(91/20)^2+3^2=(109/20)^2$.)
An other "simpler" solution is $s=-26596/1001$, $t=4-s$.
(Point not on the side segment, but on its supporting line.)

(2) The triangle with the sides $a,b,c$ equal to $4,3,5$:
The corresponding elliptic curve is:
$$
(E)
\qquad
y^2 - 12xy + 384y = x^3 + 32x^2 - 1024x - 32768
\ .
$$
It has the $2$-torsion points $(\pm 32,0)$, and $(-32,-768)$.
Its rank is one, and a generator is $(-96, -512)$.
For our problem we obtain points $s,t$ with $s+t=b=3$, and some of them are positive,
for instance for:
$$
s=\frac{147545849}{400773360}\ ,\qquad
s=\frac{12855477924158054221682513529826431795877100397}{17750547090895060157515264452002727606095230799}\ \dots
$$
Many other rational solutions $(s,t)$ with $s+t=3$, $s<$, but $s<0$ have been rejected
for geometric reasons, for instance for
$s$-values among
$\displaystyle -\frac{119}{30}$,
$\displaystyle -\frac{122187}{24871}$,
$\displaystyle -\frac{323124567298533}{6257390511689}$,
$\displaystyle -\frac{53090091712096762681}{137827568923726048290}$,
and so on.

(3)
In all experimental cases $(a,b,c)$ the rank of $E$ was at least one,
so we expect infinitely many solutions. In fact, we can reduce the analysis to the case
of a rectangle with sides
$$
a,\ b,\ c\ =\ 2t,\ t^2-1,\ t^2+1\ ,\qquad t\in \Bbb Q\ .
$$
Then a point on the associated elliptic curve $(E)$ of equation
$$
y^2 -4bxy + 8a^2by = x^3 + 2a^2 x^2 -4a^4x - 8a^6 
$$
is the point $P=(x_P,y_P)$ defined by
$$
\bbox[yellow]{
    \qquad
    P=\Big(\ -8t^2(2t-1)\ ,\ -64t^3(t-1)\ \Big)\ .
    \qquad}
$$
Then $-P$ is $-P=\Big(\ -8t^2(2t-1)\ ,\ -64t^4(t-1)\ \Big)$.
Generically, this is a point of infinite order.
(Since it is so for some specializations, for instance for $t=2$.)
We can analyze the torsion to exclude it from being a torsion point. (The two-torsion was already examined.)
So the answer to the question about the existence of infinitely many solutions on the sides,
seen as supporting lines, is positive. (To see if this is also the case for the sides, seen as segments, is an other story. In given cases the analysis can be started, but here the frame would explode.)

(4)
Since we produce elliptic curves in between, and each such elliptic curve may have a
more or less rich group of rational points, it may be of (high) interest
to study the family and see if small values for $(a,b,c)$ may produce elliptic curves $E$
of higher rank. Here is a table collecting some values for $a,b,c$, that give higher and higher ranks...
$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & \text{rank} & \text{gens} \\\hline
3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & (-90, -432) \\\hline
7 & 24 & 25 & 2 & (-1274, -115248)\\
    &&&& (-578, -2496) \\\hline
33 & 544 & 545 & 3 & (2310, 296208)\\
    &&&& (9624582, -21175021296)\\
    &&&& (599860242, -14053673696400) \\\hline
59 & 1740 & 1741 & 4 & (7198, 1670880)\\
    &&&& (5978725411/2025, -108380008570141/91125)\\
    &&&& (201309138/3721, -121402185520/226981)\\
    &&&& (4737703947/116281, 9335875040534575/39651821)\\
    \hline
4004 & 7797 & 8765 & 5 & (32253760, 31129811328)\\
    &&&& (60120060 , 1093118962936)\\
    &&&& (93641548 , 2336866732200)\\
    &&&& (110543069 , 2982694626639)\\
    &&&& (119659587168/49 , -30718101572956160/343)\\
    \hline
\end{array}
$$
The values for $(a,b,c)$ are moderate, but the corresponding elliptic curves have big coefficients.
However it is still a benefit to have a family of elliptic curves that potentially gives so many
curves of higher rank, where the generators tend to be themselves integral (or have small denominators).
All curves in the family have rank one, very often the rank is two, often enough we have rank three,
we have rank four and five for instance for...
$$
\begin{array}{|r|r|r|c|}
\hline
a & b & c & \text{rank} \\\hline
59 & 1740 & 1741 & 4\\
103 & 5304 & 5305 & 4\\
123 & 7564 & 7565 & 4\\
756 & 2867 & 2965 & 4\\
984 & 1537 & 1825 & 4\\
1104 & 4697 & 4825 & 4\\
1365 & 1892 & 2333 & 4\\
1485 & 9052 & 9173 & 4\\
1560 & 3431 & 3769 & 4\\
1584 & 7663 & 7825 & 4\\
1605 & 5612 & 5837 & 4\\
1608 & 4345 & 4633 & 4\\
2040 & 4399 & 4849 & 4\\
2093 & 12876 & 13045 & 4\\
2449 & 2640 & 3601 & 4\\
2585 & 408 & 2617 & 4\\
2781 & 4940 & 5669 & 4\\
2852 & 3315 & 4373 & 4\\
2921 & 7800 & 8329 & 4\\
3395 & 4092 & 5317 & 4\\
3397 & 2196 & 4045 & 4\\
3429 & 7700 & 8429 & 4\\
3431 & 1560 & 3769 & 4\\
4773 & 7636 & 9005 & 4\\
4779 & 1540 & 5021 & 4\\
6059 & 780 & 6109 & 4\\
6063 & 7216 & 9425 & 4\\
6272 & 1695 & 6497 & 4\\
6279 & 12200 & 13721 & 4\\
6307 & 5676 & 8485 & 4\\
6435 & 9212 & 11237 & 4\\
6640 & 5289 & 8489 & 4\\
6873 & 664 & 6905 & 4\\
7144 & 3567 & 7985 & 4\\
8360 & 7089 & 10961 & 4\\
8715 & 2068 & 8957 & 4\\
9660 & 139 & 9661 & 4\\
10488 & 1015 & 10537 & 4\\
10488 & 5215 & 11713 & 4\\
10492 & 3675 & 11117 & 4\\
10680 & 4321 & 11521 & 4\\
10716 & 5587 & 12085 & 4\\
13800 & 5239 & 14761 & 4\\    
\hline
4004 & 7797 & 8765 & 5\\
4005 & 2948 & 4973 & 5\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Appendix:
The following sage code may be used to investigate some special cases.
def get_points(a, b, c, verbose=False, only_E=False, limit=6):
    R1.<x, y> = QQ[]
    R2.<u, v> = QQ[]
    
    H = Curve( -v^2 + a^2*(u^2 + 1)^2 + 4*a*b*u*(u^2 - 1) + 4*b^2*u^2 )
    
    A, B, C, D, q = a^2, 4*a*b, 2*a^2 + 4*b^2, -4*a*b, a
    Q = 2*q
    # a1, a2, a3, a4 = D/q, C - D^2/Q^2, Q*B, -Q^2*A
    # a6 = a2*a4
    a1, a2, a3, a4, a6 = -4*b, 2*a^2, 8*a^2*b, -4*a^4, -8*a^6
    
    E = EllipticCurve( [a1, a2, a3, a4, a6] )
    
    def U(x, y):
        return  2*a/y * (x + 2*a^2)
    
    def V(x, y):
        u = U(x, y)
        return u/2/a*(u*x + 4*a*b) - a
    
    T1 = E.point(( 2*a^2, 0))
    T2 = E.point((-2*a^2, 0))
    T3 = E.point((-2*a^2, -16*a^2*b))

    if only_E:
        return E

    gens = E.gens()
    if verbose:
        print(f"{E}")
        print(f"Torsion order: {E.torsion_order()}")
        print(f"Is {T1.xy()} a 2-torsion point? {T1.order() == 2}")
        print(f"Is {T2.xy()} a 2-torsion point? {T2.order() == 2}")
        print(f"Is {T3.xy()} a 2-torsion point? {T3.order() == 2}")
        print(f"E has RANK: {E.rank()}")
        print(f"Generator(s): {gens}")
    
    ngens = len(gens)
    CP = cartesian_product([[0,1], [0,1]] + [[-limit..limit] for P in gens])
    points = [T1, T2] + gens
    PLIST = [sum(j*P for j, P in zip(coeffs, points)) for coeffs in CP]
    PLIST = [P for P in PLIST if P and P[1]]
    PxyLIST = [P.xy() for P in PLIST]
    QuvLIST = [(U(*Pxy), V(*Pxy)) for Pxy in PxyLIST]

    QLIST = [H.point(Quv) for Quv in QuvLIST]
    RLIST = []

    for (u, v) in QLIST:
        if not u:
            continue
        S, T = v/(2*u), a/(2*u) * (u^2 + 1)
        s, t = sqrt(S^2 - a^2), sqrt(T^2 - a^2)
        if s > t:
            s, t = t, s
    
        for [es, et] in cartesian_product([[-1, 1], [-1, 1]]):
            s1, t1 = s*es, t*et
            if s1 + t1 == b:
                RLIST.append((s1, t1))
    
    RLIST = list(set(RLIST))
    SOLS  = []             
    for s, t in RLIST:
        if s > 0 and t > 0:
            if verbose:
                print(f"SOLUTION: s = {s} and t = {t}")
            SOLS.append((s, t))
        else:
            if verbose:
                print(f"\t\t\t... IGNORED:  s = {s} and t = {t}")
    
    SOLS.sort(key=lambda sol: sol[0].height())        
    return (E, SOLS)

Example of usage:
# get some cases with elliptic curves of rank > 1
abc_list = [(2*m*n, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2)
            for m in [1..100] for n in [1..m-1]
            if gcd(m, n) == 1]

abc_list += [(b, a, c) for (a, b, c) in abc_list]
abc_list = [(a/gcd([a,b,c]), b/gcd([a,b,c]), c/gcd([a,b,c])) for (a, b, c) in abc_list]

abc_list = list(set(abc_list))
abc_list.sort()

a0 = 0
higher_rank_data = []
for a, b, c in abc_list:
    if a > a0:
        print('..........', a, b, c)
        a0 = a
    E = get_points(a, b, c, only_E=1)
    # E.simon_two_descent(verbose=1, lim1=30, lim3=500, limbigprime=100)
    try:
        r = E.rank()
    except:
        pass
    if r > 2:
        print(f"\n\nRANK {r} :: a = {a} :: b = {b} :: c = {c}")
        # E, sols = get_points(a, b, c, verbose=True, limit=3)
        higher_rank_data.append((r, a, b, c, E))


Nice analysis. For question 1: My approach is similar to yours. I am trying to prove that there are infinitely many points on the "side segment" of the rectangle. One approach I am trying is: start from one (may be carefully chosen) solution P on the x-axis and repeatedly add the point to itself. And prove that this process eventually gives a point on the "side segment".
